# How to cancel trigger after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

On my website, I have a closed accordion menu (menu-1). If the user doesn't click on the menu for the first 5 seconds of being on the site, the menu drops down automatically using this js code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#menu-1').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

My problem is when the user doesn't wait 5 seconds, and clicks on the menu before the trigger, the trigger still goes off and ends up closing the menu. How do make it so that the trigger is canceled if the user clicks on the menu before its triggered?

Comment: try with conditions

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the timeout ID in a variable, so you can later cancel it if  the user clicks on the menu. Like this...

```
var timeout_id = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#menu-1').trigger('click');
}, 5000);

$('#menu-1').click(function() {
    if (timeout_id) {
        clearTimeout(timeout_id);
        timeout_id = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: The variable is working but the menu still ends up closing after the user opens it

Comment: @AlexKhomyakov Perhaps you might accept this as the answer?